# function syntax is off,

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this working in the woocommerce content-product.php, but i don't want to modify the core files.

So I tried to make a function to use add action

```
<p style="font-size:11px;">
  <?php
    if ( is_page( array ( 571,558 )) ) {
        echo "Melts To:";
    } elseif ( has_term( 'ice' ) ) {    
        echo "Melts To:";
    } else {
        echo " ";
    }
  ?><strong>
  <?php 
    echo $product->get_attribute('melts-to');
  ?></strong>
</p>

function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title() {
    $melts = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'melts-to' );

    foreach( $melts as $melt ) {

        if( is_page( array ( 571, 558 ) ) ) {
            echo "<p style='font-size:11px;'> Melts To: <strong>" ;
            echo $melt->name ;
            echo "</strong></p>" ;
        } elseif ( has_term( 'ice' ) ) {
            echo "Melts To:";
            echo $melt->name ;
        } else {
            echo " ";
        };
    };
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 10, 0 );
```

I am way off of getting the attribute of Melts to as it only echos the html. Any guidance is GREAT aside from continued study of php, Thanks in advace.

Comment: `$product->id` is obviously undefined.

Comment: Got lazy and just used a function include and add_action of the original code with global $product; to define outside the loop. Function creation for another day.